# SWRL: restrict a rule to a specific individual

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api, swrl

Lets say there is a class "Food" containing  individuals  "Grain" and "Fruit" . 
If i want to select  Grain i can assign a `food_type` data Property to individuals

```
(class) Food
    (ind_1) Grain   food_type ---> "grain_food"
    (ind_2) Fruit   food_type ---> "fruit_food"
```

and run this code:

```
  Food(?x) ^ food_type(?x,"grain_food") -> sqwrl:select(?x)
```

but what if i want to do this job (select  `Grain` individual) without the needing to `food_type` property? is it possible to directly point to a specific individual just by its name?

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but yes, you can use an individual in a SWRL rule.  E.g., if you have an individual **c** from class **C**, you can do:

C(c) ⟶ sqwrl:select(c)

As long as **sqwrl:select** doesn't necessarily require a variable (i.e., as long as it can accept an individual directly), this should be fine.  If it requires a variable, as opposed to an individual directly (which would go against the intent, I think), I guess you could use some kind of equality predicate, like [**swrbl:equal**](http://www.daml.org/swrl/proposal/builtins.html#8.1):

swrlb:equal(c,?x) ⟶ sqwrl:select(?x)

Comment: `sqwrl:select` is a built-in predicate of the SWRL query language SQWRL

Comment: @AKSW Updated accordingly.